# Get Company ID values of Bluetooth device

Tags: android, bluetooth

How I can use android.bluetooth.BluetoothAssignedNumbers.
I want get Company ID values of Bluetooth device.
I can not found any examples about it.

Comment: Hey did you get any success on this.. I am looking out for the same..

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution to this? I need the company id so that I can set the right vendor specific company id action.

Comment: Actual no, I didn't find solution. I checked device by mac address that may have info about company id

Answer (score 1):

from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39896379/1739847

```
ScanRecord scanRecord = scanResult.getScanRecord();
SparseArray<byte[]> manufacturerData = scanRecord.getManufacturerSpecificData();
for(int i = 0; i < manufacturerData .size(); i++){
    int manufacturerId = manufacturerData.keyAt(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

result.getScanRecord().getBytes()

The company identifier is the two bytes after the byte that has the value -1.

The position changes depending on the the device so you just have to loop through the byte array.

```
byte[] bytes = result.getScanRecord().getBytes();
String companyID = "";

for(int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
   if(bytes[i] == -1) {
      companyID = companyID + String.format("%02X", bytes[i+1]) + String.format("%02X", bytes[i+2]);
      break;
   }
}
```