# Bytes in manufaturer specific data of bluetooth advertisements keep on changing

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I'm using a `BluetoothLeScanner` present in Android API levels 21+. In the `onScanResult(int callbackType, final ScanResult result)` of `ScanCallback`. I want to get the bytes of the manufacturer specific data from the advertisement frame.

When I do a `result.getScanRecord().getManufacturerSpecificData(2)`, I get a `byte[]` array of the company with 16 bit Id of `0x0002` which can be directly logged as a hex string of the form `[B@5db845a`.

I use an nRF Connect Android app on another phone and from there Advertise with company Id `0x0002` and some fixed other bytes of data.

However, my `BluetoothLeScanner` phone sees the above-said bytes like `[B@5db845a` continuously changing in the logged output. There is no other device advertising with same company Id close by. I even changed the company Id to `0x0006` and tried.

Why are these bytes changing? I need to take some decision in my app based on fixed bytes in this data. Am I missing something?

Comment: I would question why you are using 2 as the manufacturerID as the input for getManufacturerSpecificData(2) - are you sure the ID of the manufacturer is not changing? There is a separate question about getting manufacturer data here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39889598/how-to-filter-on-manufacturer-data-when-using-bluetoothlescanner-for-android with a slightly different implementation

Comment: Replying to @lintfordpickle , I have seen the data without applying a filter. I get Manufacturer data as a Sparse Array. The Manufacturer Id (2 Bytes) doesn't change. But the rest bytes do change.

Answer (score 0):

**Answering my own question after finding something that works:**

I did some reading on this and then while searching online for something else related to the same project and which also dealt in a byte array and hex string I stumbled upon something. I can't remember the link of the question to cite it but it went something like:

Dumping the `result.getScanRecord().getManufacturerSpecificData(2)` directly in the log doesn't give an error but it actually doesn't get cast or dumped properly as a string.

You need one of the following 2 methods to observe the data properly:

1. `finalString = new String(byteArray)` .eg. `new String(result.getScanRecord().getManufacturerSpecificData(2))` This will give an o/p log like `�B��u����j�oL`. But, you'll have to go online and use raw string to hex string converters to check it. But, there is a catch that online converters may have a different complement system and may consider null bytes as `0xFF` instead of `0x00`. So, `0x000000030503` may become `...ff3f5f3`. Or else you can see the integer value at each element in the byte array using the below
2. `finalString = Arrays.toString(byteArray)` .eg. `Arrays.toString(result.getScanRecord().getManufacturerSpecificData(2))`. This gives an o/p `[0, 0, 0, 3, 5, 3]`. Although and `int[]` array but you can always check integer to hex values online for each element in this array.